# what is the difference of these two json output?

Tags: php, json

I have one json result in two ways.

first one is output of my external api:

```
{"result":"success","totalresults":1,"products":{"product":[{"pid":"1","gid":"1","type":"hostingaccount","name":"product1","description":"product description","module":"directadmin","paytype":"recurring","pricing":{"usd":{"prefix":"","suffix":"USD","msetupfee":"0.00","qsetupfee":"0.00","ssetupfee":"0.00","asetupfee":"0.00","bsetupfee":"0.00","tsetupfee":"0.00","monthly":"-1.00","quarterly":"-1.00","semiannually":"-1.00","annually":"199000.00","biennially":"-1.00","triennially":"-1.00"}},"customfields":{"customfield":[]},"configoptions":{"configoption":[]}}]}}
```

and second one is output of my internal api :

```
Array
(
    [result] => success
    [totalresults] => 1
    [products] => Array
        (
            [product] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [pid] => 1
                            [gid] => 1
                            [type] => hostingaccount
                            [name] => product1
                            [description] => <div class="title col-xs-12">Plan BL2</div>
                                    <div class="disk item col-xs-12">5 GB</div>
                                    <div class="bandwidth item col-xs-12">50 GB</div>
                                    <div class="database item col-xs-12">4</div>
                                    <div class="parkdomain item col-xs-12">10</div>
                                    <div class="adddomain item col-xs-12"><i class="icon icon-cancel"></i></div>
                                    <div class="support item col-xs-12"><i class="icon icon-ok"></i></div>
                            [module] => directadmin
                            [paytype] => recurring
                            [pricing] => Array
                                (
                                    [USD] => Array
                                        (
                                            [prefix] => 
                                            [suffix] =>  USD
                                            [msetupfee] => 0.00
                                            [qsetupfee] => 0.00
                                            [ssetupfee] => 0.00
                                            [asetupfee] => 0.00
                                            [bsetupfee] => 0.00
                                            [tsetupfee] => 0.00
                                            [monthly] => -1.00
                                            [quarterly] => -1.00
                                            [semiannually] => -1.00
                                            [annually] => 199000.00
                                            [biennially] => -1.00
                                            [triennially] => -1.00
                                        )

                                )

                            [customfields] => Array
                                (
                                    [customfield] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                            [configoptions] => Array
                                (
                                    [configoption] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

in first one I can print parameters for example price in this case by this code:

```
$url = 'internal api url';
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$array = [];
foreach($obj['products'] as $value){
    $array[$value[0]['pid']] = $value[0];
}
echo "<div class="price item col-xs-12">'.(int)$array[$atts['aprice']]['pricing']['USD']['annually'].' USD</div>";
```

but not successful in second one.
any help?

Comment: Root element in the first json is object, in the second one - array. Just an idea.

Comment: First is a JSON String. Second is a PHP Array.

Comment: There could be valid question here (probably duplicate if php has any code to read JSON or PHP), but definitely not related to question in the title. Please consider to [edit] post to clarify what you actually want (or flag to delete).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because second one is not JSON string. It looks like PHP array dump, so you can't decode it.
You need to encode the array before returning to get JSON string that you'll be able to parse

Comment: Thanks, Now how to print price(annually) in this PHP array dump? @Filip

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$obj['products']['product'][0]['pricing']['USD']['annually']` with your internal API.

Comment: How do you get the second output ?

Comment: It's an whmcs local api. first one is an external api (CURL). more : https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/getproducts/

Comment: I mean, what is exactly the code you use to get the second output with your internal API ?

Comment: The code is in local api section in this page: https://developers.whmcs.com/api-reference/getproducts/

Comment: the url of output is http://adu.ir/lFmJ6 . I want to print for example annually price of pid=68 that equal to 50000 IRR in this case.

Comment: Then use `$results = localAPI($command, $postData, $adminUsername);` then `$results['products']['product'][0]['pricing']['USD']['annually']`...